# Why I can commit a change from a different branch than the one I staged it?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I am on branch `master`. I create a new file e.g. `Util.java` . This is untracked. So I do `git add Util.java` and the file is in the staging area ready for commit.
Then I do `git checkout -b temp` so I switch to the `temp` branch.
On `git status` I see that there is the file `Util.java` staged and ready to be commited. I did not expect this since I assumed that once I switch branch, everything is clean.
I do `git commit Util.java` and the file is commited and the `git log` graph shows that `Util.java` is part of the branch of `temp`. I.e. it follows another "timeline" than the one of `master`.
Why does this work like that? I was expecting to not be to commit `Util.java` since I created it on a different branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a git branch, you aren't creating a fresh branch. You are in effect creating a branch from whichever branch you are on when you create it.

To clarify: There is a pointer to the current revision that is known as HEAD. Your head will specify the base of whatever new branches you create. In this specific instance, since you were on your branch that had an added file, your HEAD was pointing to your current branch. When you create a new branch, your current file status is used as the base, even if your local changes aren't reflected in git versioning yet.

If you really want to make a clean branch you should checkout whatever is your definition of a "clean" branch. Usually master, and then branch from there. That should wipe out whatever changes you've made on your local branch.

If you want a good intuitive visual way to understand how HEAD and master and branching all work I HIGHLY recommend this tutorial: http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/

If you want you can even fork it and make new examples, but just going through it will teach you a lot about git.

If you want a deeper understanding of git add and why it's different from git commit I suggest reading the man page for `git add` found [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html)